# elasticsearch mapping for english IT job listings including synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

I'm trying to come up with a reasonable mapping in Elasticsearch to search for IT job listings. These job listings in particular have loads of technical terms with a bunch of synonyms. e.g.: `node.js, nodeJS, node` or `ruby on rails, ruby-on-rails, ror`, etc.

I'd like to come up with a mapping with a preference of recall over precision that also takes synonyms into account.

What would be a good mapping for this? Specifically, looking for a mapping that's been tried and tested in the field of (technical) job listings.

Currently, having the following which does a good job at:

- no stemming!
- removing stopwords
- removing html tags
- Recall: finding `node.js` when searching for `node`, etc.

Problem is the 'advanced' synonyms, e.g.: RoR <=> ruby-on-rails. 
How would I go about this?

```
  {
     "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "english_stop": {
            "type":       "stop",
            "stopwords":  "_english_" 
          }
        },
        "tokenizer" : {
            "technicalTermTokenizer" : {
                "type" : "edgeNGram",
                "min_gram" : "2",
                "max_gram" : "20",
                "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit", "symbol", "punctuation" ]
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "jobsAnalyzer": {
            "type":         "custom",
            "char_filter":  [ "html_strip"],
            "tokenizer":  "standard",
            "filter": [
              "english_stop"
            ]
          },
          "jobsAnalyzer_edgeGram" : {
            "type":         "custom",
            "char_filter":  [ "html_strip"],
            "tokenizer" : "technicalTermTokenizer",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "english_stop"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "jobs": {
        "properties": {
          "skills": {
           "type" : "multi_field",
           "fields":{
              "skills": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "edge" : {
                "type" : "string", 
                "index_analyzer": "jobsAnalyzer_edgeGram", 
                "search_anaylzer": "jobsAnalyzer_edgeGram"
              }
           }
          },
          "title": {
            "type" : "multi_field",
            "fields" : {
              "title" : {
                "type" : "string", 
                "analyzer": "jobsAnalyzer"
              },
              "edge" : {
                "type" : "string", 
                "index_analyzer": "jobsAnalyzer_edgeGram", 
                "search_anaylzer": "jobsAnalyzer"
              }
            }
          },
          "desc_full": {
            "type" : "multi_field",
            "fields" : {
              "desc_full" : {
                "type" : "string", 
                "analyzer": "jobsAnalyzer"
              },
              "edge" : {
                "type" : "string", 
                "index_analyzer": "jobsAnalyzer_edgeGram", 
                "search_anaylzer": "jobsAnalyzer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

A query may be as follows:

```
"query": {
    "multi_match": {
        "query":    "node",
        "fields":   [ "title", "title.edge", "desc_full", "desc_full.edge", "skills", "skills.edge" ]
    }
  },
```